# mutex as class member

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex

```
 class temp
 {
    boost::mutex mx;
    void CriticalCode() {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(mx); 
        //Do Something
        return;
    }
 }
```

1. If this class is allocated on the heap (`temp* T = new temp()`), will this be thread safe (for each instance, not all instances together)?
2. If I make `boost::mutex mx` -> `boost::mutex* mx`, and allocate it in the constructor so it will be allocated on the heap, will the code be thread safe also?
3. If answer to 1 and 2 are no, how can I make each instance thread safe?

Comment: Why people talk about "stack" and "heap" when they can talk "automatic" and "dynamic" allocation.

Comment: on point 2, there is absolutely no need for that. The ONLY reason to make it a pointer (and even then, I would make it a reference) would be to pass in a mutex to the instance during construction - i.e. you have a single mutex that you want all instances to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1)if this class is allocated on the heap (temp* T = new temp()) , will this be thread safe (for each instance, not all instances together ?**

Yes. Since mx is not a static member of the class, there will be one lock per instance of the class.

**2)if i make boost::mutex mx -> boost::mutex* mx , and allocate it in the constructor so it will be allocated on the heap , will the code be thread safe also ?**

Yes. But thread safe only on a per-instance basis.

**3)if answer to 1 and 2 are now , how can i make each instance thread safe ?**

The answers are yes so you are fine.

In case, someone else wonders how to make all instances thread safe with one lock -- you can make mx a static variable of the class.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, this depends greatly on where and how the static instance is constructed (i.e lazy is not inherrently thread safe!). If you end up taking this approach - you REALLY need to review your design.

Comment: I see. I am not on top of lazy static variables. The computer scientist in me does tell me that the term implies that the allocation isnt done until the variable is in fact written to. That still sounds thread-safe to me but I may be missing something, Can you tell me more?

Comment: there are two ways of using statics in a given class. One way is to declare them as static members directly and then in a translation unit actually define them (the problem here is that you are then dependent on order of initialization - and this is not guaranteed). The workaround to this is to declare the object as a static within a static function of the class and return a reference to that static instance - this is the lazy initialisation I was talking of. However this is not inherrently threadsafe (the standard specifies nothing on threading and therefore who constructs).

Comment: ...i.e. if two threads enter the static function to get the lock and no one has called this function before, there is no guarantee as to who constructs. One way around this would be to have some sort of global initialization before the threads are created which calls this static function to construct the mutex... Other option is to simply pass in a mutex when constructing the `temp` object and only have a reference to a mutex in `temp`.

Answer (score 3):

The storage location has nothing to do with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the method `CriticalCode()` will be thread safe in both cases.